# Integrating Orbeon with custom Java web application

Tags: java, integration, orbeon

We want to integrate Orbeon with Java web application. I read the documentation at https://doc.orbeon.com/, but haven't found all the answers I was looking for.

Before we decide to use Orbeon I would like to have some answers.

1. When you create a form (survey), is it posible to have a custum identificaton of the document, when the user answers the survey?

   As I can see each answer gets a unique documentid. Can you have your own id which consists of multiple fields, like company, user, instance,...
2. We have the same survey which has to be answered each month. How can we achieve this in Orbeon?

   Can we create a new form, which has the month field and then using URLs or API in our application to pass the value into the month field, soo the user doesn't need to fill this field and doesnt even see it?
   So basicaly the question is, can we create a new document using URLs or API with passing custum data into the document, soo the user doesn't have to and we can manage this data in our own application.
3. When the user completes the survey is it posible to edit it again or is it "closed"?

To make things more clear what we want to do let me explain what we want to achieve.
Our web application has many users. We want to give each user a survey each month (they will have different surveys based on the logged user). We want to link our web app with orbeon forms either by using URLs or orbeon API.
Scenario would be:

1. User logs on to our web app, and sees that he has one (or more) servey to complete.
2. When he clikes somewere, our app opens orbeon form
3. When the user completes the servey we need to know (in our app) that he finished the servey. We need to link the document in orbeon whith data in our app.

I know we can do this technicaly on the database level (we use Oracle) or using API or calles from orbeon to a web service, but we need to have the same data (userId or some other data) in order to link them together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try to answer to your questions below. I won't go into all the technical details for each one, but this will already give you some idea, if even only at a high level.

1. Like you said, when users fill out a new form, Orbeon Forms automatically assigns to every instance of a new form a new id, the so-called *document id*. If users come back to edit the form, the document id is unchanged. You can't tell Orbeon Forms what document id to use, however you can have some information, say a token, stored as part of the form data, so you can then find the data based on the token. This token typically comes from a request parameter or an HTTP header (if set by a servlet filter or reverse proxy). Also, if users are logged in, Orbeon Forms will store the username along with the data.
2. You can create a new instance programmatically using the API. It requires a few calls to the API, and is thus [more complicated than it could be](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/3080), ideally, but it is certainly possible.
3. If users a logged in, which seems to be the case in the system you have in mind, using [permissions](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/access-control/deployed-forms.html), you can do both: form authors can decide whether users should be allowed to back and edit data that was previously saved.

Comment: Thank you for answering so quickly. Can I ask you one more question. I know that it is possible to duplicate a form, but is it possible to duplicate an answered survey based on token(document id). We want to have have the functionality, that when a user finishes a survey, that he has the option to answer it again using previous answers. He than corrects only the questions that he wants.

Comment: @OracleDev Yes, there is an API that you can call to [duplicate form data](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/api/other/duplicate-form-data.html). Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: @OracleDev Also, I created an [RFE](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/3080) for a new API that would make it simpler to create new form data programmatically, and added a +1 from you there.

Comment: Yes, this was what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: @OracleDev Excellent, I am glad it helped.